# Why is 'were' used here instead of 'was'?

Tags: archaic-language, modality

In Herodotus 3.81 :

> Megabyzus spoke next, and advised the setting up of an oligarchy:- "In all that Otanes has said to persuade you to put down monarchy," he observed, "I fully concur; but his recommendation that we should call the people to power seems to me not the best advice. For there is nothing so void of understanding, nothing so full of wantonness, as the unwieldy rabble. It **were** folly not to be borne, for men, while seeking to escape the wantonness of a tyrant, to give themselves up to the wantonness of a rude unbridled mob. ..."

Comment: It is a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **hypothetical situation** is posed which uses the subjunctive **were**.
If the action **actually happened**, **was** would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Peter's ANSWER.

This is a Victorian translation, now more than a hundred and fifty years old, and it employs (as did most translations of that era) a diction which was already very  old-fashioned.

This *were* would ordinarily be expressed *would be* today.